# UITableViewCell text alignment and overlapped by subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a todo list application. It's however i cant seems to align my checkbox image properly with the cell.textLabel.text.

My problem for the code below is the words "test test" got cover by my checkbox image, which only left with "st test"

My code for the checkbox button image like

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 7.0, 25.0, 25.0)];

UIImage *uncheckedButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox.png"];

[button setImage:uncheckedButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

and my cell textlabel is just

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"test test";
```

Is there anyway the align the textLabel text to move a bit to the right?

Comment: why don't use UILabel as a view and add it to the Cell, you will be having more control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to look at the "Indentation" properties of UITableViewCell.  See the documentation for more info.  Subclassing the cell and adding your own UILabel would give you the most control though.

Answer (score 1):

I have suggested to Add UILabel because in the future if you needed to change the view cell it will be more Dynamic and easier to play around anything new to the Cell.

take a look to the following code snippet:

```
    CGRect DeviceNameFrame = CGRectMake(101, 32, 522, 21);

    UILabel *lblDeviceName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:DeviceNameFrame];   
    lblDeviceName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblDeviceName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17];
    lblDeviceName.text =  @"test test";
    lblDeviceName.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDeviceName];
    [lblDeviceName release];
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: hi Ahmad, if i use this solution, then when i "swipe to delete", the delete button will overlap with the text in uitableviewcell. Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: @lucas: You want the UILabel to be over the Delete button on swipe?